# How Can Refresh RecyclerView Items After Update

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a `RecyclerView` and I update the Data in the adapter, my problem is that After Change I can not refresh `RecyclerView` Data.

i used `notifyDataSetChanged();` but is doesn't work

UpdateStudent edits the student name, the problem is that after the change, `RecyclerView` needs to refresh list

#### ReyclerView Adapter :

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter_StudentList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    List<StudentTable> tableData = new ArrayList<>();

    Context context;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter_StudentList(Context context, List<StudentTable> tableData) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.tableData = tableData;
    }

    public class itemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView studentName;

        return new itemHolder(view);
    }
}
```

#### onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    itemHolder itemHolder = (itemHolder) holder;

    String studentName = tableData.get(position).getStudentName();

    itemHolder.studentName.setText(studentName);

    itemHolder.editStudent_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {           
            String studentName_new = studentName_EditText.getText().toString();

            database.UpdateStudent(classId , studentName_new);

            notifyDataSetChanged();// does not work           
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to see what you're doing in UpdateStudent. :)

Comment: UpdateStudent only edits the student name, the problem is that after the change, RecyclerView needs to update

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
itemHolder.editStudent_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {           
        String studentName_new = studentName_EditText.getText().toString();            
        database.UpdateStudent(classId , studentName_new);

        StudentTable student = tableData.get(position);
        student.setName(studentName_new);
        tableData.set(position, student);
        notifyItemChanged(position);          
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
itemHolder.editStudent_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {           
        String studentName_new = studentName_EditText.getText().toString();            
        database.UpdateStudent(classId , studentName_new);

        StudentTable student = tableData.get(position);
        student.setName(studentName_new);
         notifyItemChanged(position);

    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are **notifying only adapter without changing data list** so you need to do is
After updating retrieve data from table and store it in your current list `tableData` and then you have to call `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Yes, my problem is I do not know how to do it